# Playwright not accepting https urls while openinign with codegen command

Tags: playwright

npx playwright codegen https:/// page.goto: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID at ...

how can i open https url through codegen command by passing input params or auth credentials

Answer (score 3):

See the custom codegen setup documentation [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/cli#codegen-with-custom-setup). Based on that error you will likely need to add chrome launch argument: `--ignore-certificate-errors` and set `ignoreHTTPSErrors: true` in the launch options. Codegen can also preserve authenticated state by running with `--save-storage` flag.

Source:

- https://playwright.dev/docs/cli#preserve-authenticated-state
- https://playwright.dev/docs/cli#codegen-with-custom-setup

Comment: actually the page prompting to popup where its asking username and password,so when i try to fill with username and pwd,its not able to detect the popup username and pwd and even iam unable to open dev tools.how can i detect promoted window or popup where its asking username and pwd and click submit to proceed

Answer (score 3):

Adding `--ignore-https-errors` worked for me

`npx playwright codegen https://localhost/ --ignore-https-errors`

Comment: Adding the commandline working fine but can we add it in the playwright config or any? Each time i need to pass this arguments

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add how to use the chrome launch argument in `playwright.config`:

```js
{
    name: 'chrome web',
    use: {
        browserName: 'chromium',
        launchOptions: {
            args: ['--ignore-certificate-errors']
        }
    }
}
```

Argument is added when running `npx playwright test`

Answer (score 1):

In Playwright Sharp:

```
var context = await browser.NewContextAsync(new BrowserNewContextOptions { IgnoreHTTPSErrors = true });
```

Answer (score 0):

in package.json file
"scripts": {
"test": "playwright codegen --ignore-https-errors"
}

run command like,
npm test https://demo.co.in

each time we cannot add the ignore https errors command, better handle it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get through HTTP authentication, for example, is to start codegen without the URL and to navigate to the URL in codegen. This has the advantage that HTTP authentication can also be handled there:

- Node.js: `npx playwright codegen`
- Java: `mvn exec:java -e -D exec.mainClass=com.microsoft.playwright.CLI -D exec.args="codegen"`